# Is it a good idea to make whole theme widgetized?

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have mainly seen sites using widgets on sidebars or inside multi-column layout. However, I was wondering what if we could use widgets in every blocks like header, main content block, footer etc. Is that a good or a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad idea. Wordpress widgets were flexible but give you a low performance. In order to optimize the wordpress I used to code by myself to implement some functions, my blog's sidebar   didn't use any widget but implement all I want such as an advanced "Recent Comments" module which contains the comment author's avatar and the comment content

Answer (score 1):

That's bad form IMO.  Widgets are for special items, not for general purpose.  As for he Nav in the header and footer, use WP3's Meny functionality, gives an admin panel for menus.  Keep it simple.  Widgets all around will just make it confusing.